# Select alias/variants of data from table and group by its own data in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Have a table with some data with different variants of names.
Select variants of data from table and group by its own data in Postgres. Select the only distinct name and select a common name.

```
SELECT name FROM table;
```

**Output**

```
name
-----------------------
name 1<br>
2 name of the student 
user 1
user 1 of CA 2
something ele
```

**The result what I want**
**Result**

```
name           | count
------------------------
name           |  2
user 1         |  2
something else |  1
```

Comment: Please explain the logic for matching.  What if you have `'user 1 name'`?

Comment: Group the name where the similarity is more.

Comment: Why is `something else` considered one name, not two? And why is `name 1` treated as `name` but `user 1` is treated as `user 1` - what decides when to remove the number?

Comment: Here `something else` is one sentence there is no other word that matches this one. and  `user 1` is present in both so the max similarity is `user 1`